# duration limit for unlockAccount()

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

When I use `personal.unlockAccount()`, there is an option to pass a parameter for duration. What is the maximum duration to which i can unlock the account? I have searched through its documentation. It only tells me that the duration is in seconds. And if i pass 0 as a duration parameter, the account unlocks permanently. **But I want to know what is the maximum duration i can set.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [geth source](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/0255951587ef0eada5d162f3404bc481f70a2ce2/internal/ethapi/api.go#L320), there is a max check for the time, which is calculated based of the MaxInt64 value, and ends up as 9223372036 seconds, or roughly 292 years.

```
// UnlockAccount will unlock the account associated with the given address with
// the given password for duration seconds. If duration is nil it will use a
// default of 300 seconds. It returns an indication if the account was unlocked.
func (s *PrivateAccountAPI) UnlockAccount(addr common.Address, password string, duration *uint64) (bool, error) {
    const max = uint64(time.Duration(math.MaxInt64) / time.Second)
    var d time.Duration
    if duration == nil {
        d = 300 * time.Second
    } else if *duration > max {
        return false, errors.New("unlock duration too large")
    } else {
        d = time.Duration(*duration) * time.Second
    }
    err := fetchKeystore(s.am).TimedUnlock(accounts.Account{Address: addr}, password, d)
    return err == nil, err
}
```